# Como obtengo los valores diferentes entre array1 y array2

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, bucle-for

Quiero obtener los valores diferentes que tiene el data de  ruta
ejemplo:
como resultado me tendria que dar Piña, trate con un for dentro de un for pero no pude.

```
data= ["queso","jamon","piña"];

ruta= ["lechuga",jamon","queso"];


    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var n = 0; n < ruta.length; n++) {
            if(data[i].indexOf(ruta[n].toLowerCase()) != -1){
                var xd = data[i].indexOf(ruta[n].toLowerCase());
              //aqui me tendria que dar las frutas de data que no tiene ruta

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: pero eso es javascript  o c# ? porque la respuesta es muy distinta segun la tecnologia, con c# yo aplicaria linq en lugar de hacer dos for. Y en javascript usaria librerias como ser lodash para tener funciones que permitan trabajar con listas de items

Comment: Es JS del lado del cliente, se me colo c#, gracias.

Comment: no puede usar librerias para evitar tener que realizar dos for ? lo pregunto porque ya usas jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes obtener el resultado deseado haciendo uso de las funciones `Array.prototype.filter` y `Array.prototype.includes` de la siguiente forma:

```js
const data = ['queso', 'jamon', 'piña']
const ruta = ['lechuga', 'jamon', 'queso']

const diff = data.filter((a) => !ruta.includes(a))
```

### Array.prototype.filter

Es una funcion que te permite crear un nuevo Array a partir de uno preexistente, usando una funcion callback que te permita evaluar si el dato sera removido (en caso de que la función resulte en falsa) o mantenido (en caso de que la función retorne verdadero).

Puedes encontrar la documentación de Array.prototype.filter [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter).

### Array.prototype.includes

Esta función te permite conocer si un valor determinado se encuentra dentro de un arreglo, es similar a indexOf, con la diferencia que indexOf no tiene la capacidad de encontrar valores `undefined` y `NaN`.

igualmente puedes encontrar la documentación [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes).

Answer (score 0):

Si te animas a usar la libreria `lodash` podrias lograr lo que buscas sin realizar ningun `for`

https://lodash.com/

Un ejemplo

```js
var data = ["queso","jamon","piña"];
var ruta = ["lechuga","jamon","queso"];

var result = _.difference(data, ruta);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes realizar el siguiente ejemplo con `for`:

```js
var data= ["queso","jamon","piña"];

var ruta= ["lechuga","jamon","queso"];


    var a = [], diff = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        a[data[i]] = true;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < ruta.length; i++) {
        if (a[ruta[i]] != data[i]) {
            delete a[ruta[i]];
        } else {
            a[ruta[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    for (var val in a) {
        diff.push(val);
    }
    
    console.log(diff);
```

Espero que te ayude. Saludos.